# Writing large files and suspend

Tags: windows-store-apps

In our windows store app we save the files that the users are creating in an epub file, which is a zip archive with file extension .epub
The app is written primarily in HTML and JS, but to handle the writing to the zip archive we use some C# in a helper.

This all works, but I have found that the zip archive can become corrupted if the app suspends whilst writing to the zip, as sometimes when adding a particularly large file to the zip, say a 100mb video file, the operation does not complete in the 5 seconds allowed from oncheckpoint.

Are there any ways that I could avoid this problem? As far as I can see there is just no way to write a large file to a zip and be 100% sure that it won't get corrupted if the app suspends.

Comment: Just write to a temporary file first, rename it afterwards.  If you get suspended then you'll just leave a harmless file around, you'll catch it the next time you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that there is just no way to write a large file to a zip and be 100% sure that it won't get corrupted if the app suspends.
As far as I know, when an App was suspended, the memory owned by the app will not be released, so you don’t need to worry about the data missing in memory when suspending.
The thing you need to worry is user quit the app before the data was persistent.
But some extra designs may improve some user experience and avoid data losing.

## auto-save

For example, persistent the changes when the object was changed by user.

## show user saving progress

Using the progress UI to let user know the saving is in-progress and he/she will lost the data if quit the app.